# Number name entity recognition in Stanford

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I have a problem in which I'm trying to recognize the number name entity from a text using Stanford , in case I have for example 20 million It's retrieving like this "Number":["20-5","million-6"], How can I optimize the answer so 20 millions comes together? and How can I ignore the index number like (5,6) in the above example? I'm using java language.

```
    public void extractNumbers(String text) throws  IOException {
    number = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    n= new ArrayList<String>();
    edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation document = new edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {

            if (!token.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class).equals("O")) {

                if (token.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class).equals("NUMBER")) {
                  n.add(token.toString());
        number.put("Number",n);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You might want to expand a little bit. Which ner model did you use? What language are you using? Also a code snippet to show us exactly what you did would also help.

Comment: @entrophy I edited the question :)

Comment: which class's object is `pipeline` here. As in which Stanford pipeline are you using.

Comment: @entrophy '  
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline; Annotation annotation; Properties props = new Properties(); props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner"); pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exact text from any object of `CoreLabel` class simply use `token.originalText()` instead of `token.toString()`

If you need anything else from these tokens, take a look at `CoreLabel`'s  [javadoc](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreLabel.html).

Comment: That works fineee for my second question , thanks alot